# Throwing OutOfMemoryError when using httpclient

Tags: java, android, android-async-http

I am trying to create http request and send data to my php server. For this I am using android-async-http by loopj library. Things are working fine but when I start uploading data that are about 1600 records from my local database. I get memory leak error:

```
12917-12917/com.ylg.all E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again"
      07-29 21:56:51.852  12917-12917/com.ylg.all E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ylg.all, PID: 12917
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
        at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool.enableConnectionGC(AbstractConnPool.java:145)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.createConnectionPool(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:125)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.<init>(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:103)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.<init>(AsyncHttpClient.java:238)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.<init>(AsyncHttpClient.java:177)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.<init>(AsyncHttpClient.java:147)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2894)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Not sure how to solve this issue?

Here is the code I am trying:

I am pulling the data from local DB inside loop I am calling method. something like this:

```
List<TextDetails> unTextList = dbvalue.getTextData();
for (TextDetails td : unTextList)
{
String textID = td.getSerialNumber();
String textSMS = td.getText();
String textAddress = td.getFulladdress();
String textDate = td.getFulldate();
String textException = td.getExceptiontext();


textDetailsBackUpDataOnline(textID , textSMS, textAddress, textDate, textException);
}

private void textDetailsBackUpDataOnline(final String textID ,
String textSMS, String textAddress, String textDate, String textException)
{
final String uploadWebsite = url_backup_text_details;

RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();

requestParams.put("textSMS", textSMS);
requestParams.put("textAddress", textAddress);
requestParams.put("textDate", textDate);
requestParams.put("textException", textException);

Text_HttpClient.post(uploadWebsite, requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
{
@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody)
{
Log.e("textID", "= how many times");
}

@Override
public void onFailure(int statusCode, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e)
{
e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
});
}
```

Text_HttpClient class has the following:

```
public class Text_HttpClient 
{
private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler)
{
client.get(url, params, responseHandler);
}

public static void post(String url, RequestParams requestParams, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler)
{
client.post(url, requestParams, responseHandler);
}

}
```

Can somebody guide me on how to solve this issue? Is there a better way than above to upload text that large?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you do it in batches ? Do you have a primary key on which you can divi up the requests in batches ?

Comment: @ShreyasChavan: Can you give me a example? Are you say can I do it like first 500 and then again another 500 like that?

Comment: @SanjanaNair This problem comes from server side. There is nothing to do with android app. may be server is not capable to perform these many records. I would suggest PHP side scripting should be optimized with better PC which has more RAM & HardDisk support

Comment: @SanjanaNair Yes Im suggesting exactly what you said. That will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Lets first see how OS and HTTP works:**

When we send data to the world our OS is basically a sender right..!

So when we send large data OS makes chunks of data using predefined size and then send to the world(server).

**Now lets see how HTTP work on this data :**

- It buffers the data till the completion of data sending.
- After completion of the sending of whole large data it goes to
  process that data further.

*So though our OS sends data in chunks it does not process in chunks* right...!

**In your case :** you are sending large data to server. Your OS could send it and even server could receive it but (may be) HTTP or server couldn't handle it.

**Solution is:** So best way if your data is independent then send data in chunks that server could handle it.

In your case data is independent so you can **read and send some records at a time** to server. You can use loop for sending whole data.

**EDIT :**

**Bingo ... it is not really server error !**

See your logs, it is telling that it couldn't create thread.

```
AsyncTask is a thread internally.
```

Because of less memory Android's memory allocations for processes is bit different than the Desktop OSs.See in android's process management view, Android doesn't allocate too big memory for a process.

Your OS couldn't handle this much data reading and loading for HTTP request, result is application crashed before sending data to the world.

Solution for the problem is still same, just I have edited the cause ... :) !